# How do I know which argument throws an exception in Python (with OpenCV)?

Tags: python, opencv

Python (with OpenCV) throws the following TypeError. But I have no idea which argument is throwing it. How can I tell?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "u.py", line 18, in <module>
    out = unravel2(img,pupil)
  File "/home/chris/code/opencv/iris/support.py", line 57, in unravel2
    cv2.logPolar(img, out, center, cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)
TypeError: a float is required
```

For background, here is my code:

```
def unravel2(img, pupil):
  out = np.zeros((max_radius-min_radius,720,3), np.uint8)
  center = (297.5,234.5)
  cv2.logPolar(img, out, center, cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)

  return out
```

Comment: Which ever one is not a `float`

Comment: None of them are floats- and AFAIK none of them are meant to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you got the args for logPolar wrong (probably from the older cv api wrapper)

```
>>> import cv2
>>> help(cv2.logPolar)
Help on built-in function logPolar in module cv2:

logPolar(...)
    logPolar(src, center, M, flags[, dst]) -> dst
```

(M is the float in question)

Comment: Amazing! You are my HERO! :)

Comment: ;) unfortunately the docs are outdated on this. so better rely on the builtin help, which will at least query the module you're using